# How does find and printf work when using pipes in bash scripting

Tags: bash, scripting, find

Suppose I use the printf in the find command like this:

```
     find ./folder -printf "%f\n" | other command which uses the result of printf
```

in the other command part, I may be having a sort or something similar

what exactly does printf do in this case? where does it print the file names before the process in the part after "|" happens?

if I sort the filenames for example, it will first sort them, and then print them sorted on the monitor, but before that, how exactly does the part after | get the files unsorted in order to sort them? does the printf in this case give the filenames as input to the part after | and then the part after | prints the file names sorted in the output?

sorry for my english :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your shell calls `pipe()` which creates two file descriptors.  Writing into one buffers data in the kernel which is available to be read by the other.  Then it calls `fork()` to make a new process for the `find` command.  After the `fork()` it closes `stdout` (always fd 1) and uses `dup2()` to copy one end of the pipe to `stdout`.  Then it uses `exec()` to run `find` (replacing the copy of the shell in the subprocess with `find`).  When `find` runs it just prints to `stdout` as normal, but it has inherited it from the shell which made it the pipe.  Meanwhile the shell is doing the same thing for `other command...` with `stdin` so that it is created with fd 0 connected to the other end of the pipe.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is how pipes work. The output from the first process is the input to the second. In terms of implementation, the shell creates a socket which receives input from the first process from its standard output, and writes output to the second process on its standard input.

... You should perhaps read an introduction to Unix shell programming if you have this type of questions.